# How can I check that I run the application on my server means localhost:portnumber or hosted them on the internet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I have a MVC application; in development machine the debug path goes something like `localhost:`.

I can check that url of the request my server have is localhost or application hosted on server means they are  online.

How  can I find out that my application is on development machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`HttpRequest.IsLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx)

Comment: If his dev machine has non-local clients, that won't help.

Comment: @SLaks Indeed, but the wording of the question suggested it was being accessed locally through the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Request.Url.Hostname` and `Request.Url.Port`.
This will tell you the URL that the user requested.

Alternatively, check `Environment.MachineName`.